# Unable to create Angular2-cli RC.6 project

Tags: angular

I am using angular2-cli to generate new porject

ng new first-data-project

But the package.json shows Angular RC-4 project, while I want RC-6.
Package.josn is :-

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
```

How can I force angular-cli to make RC-6 project

Comment: angular-cli does not support RC6 as of now, you may upgrade package.json yourself however you will also have to configure SystemJS config yourself.

Comment: Does it support rc5.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `npm i -g angular-cli@webpack` to generate > RC4 projects.
If you want to stay with SystemJS, you'll have to stick with the old CLI release and handle updating yourself.